# how to break the for loop with respect to other for loop

Tags: java

i saw how to break the loop (using label and break the label) .. but i want to break the first for loop depends on the second for loop :

for example :

```
public class HelloWorld {

    static private int i;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int y = 20;
        for (; y <= 30; y += 2) 
        {
            System.out.printf("value of increamented  y Value is %d\n", y);
            increamentiValue();
        }
    }

    private static void increamentiValue() 
    {
        i = 0;
        for (; i <= 5; i += 2) {
            System.out.printf("value of i is %d\n", i);
        }
    }
}
```

for instance here i want to break the "y" loop depends on the number of iteration in "i" loop ..

for ex:

i want to break "y" for loop if the number iteriation in "i" loop is equal to 0 .. because in my program "i" checks the error ... in my ysytem error may occur any "i" .. if two times i dosnt have error (i==0) i want to break the "y" loop.

EX :
if
At y= 22 , i ==0; (no error occurs)
at y= 23 , i ==0; (no error occurs)

i dont want to proceed till 30. i want to break y loop .

Comment: Code is indented with four spaces, not with `>`.

Comment: Please take the time to ensure your code is formatted readably. I've done it for you on this occasion.

Comment: Please change `int y=20;for(; y<=30...` to `for(int y=20; j<=30...`. It is easier to read and understand.

Comment: Why use a `for` loop but put the initializer above it? Why use an *instance variable* in your `for` loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have `increamenti_Value` return a value that `main` uses to terminate the loop.

---

Separately, though, using an *instance* variable (`i`) in the `for` loop in `increamenti_Value` is a very suspect thing to do. It's also quite odd to use a `for` loop, leave out the initializer clause, and yet set the initial condition on the line above.

Comment: can u give me an example ... as i am one  week old in java

Comment: @user2965711: I'm afraid I can't, because it's not clear what you mean by *"i want to break "y" for loop if the number iteriation in "i" loop is equal to 0"* Because you're setting `i` to `0` in the function, it will always loop three times (when `i == 0`, `i == 2`, `i == 4`, all of which are `<= 5` which is the loop termination condition).

Comment: in my case .. "i" is a error check ... in my system error can fall between (i= 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 or 5) sometimes error wont fall  .. hence  if 2 times error not falls i want to break the "y"loop

Comment: @user2965711: I'm sorry, I think you need to have a friend or coworker help you with your English. Your question and comments are not at all clear. What does "if 2 times error not fails" mean? You're doing some operation twice and it needs to not fail both times? You've tried it twice and one of them worked?

Comment: np .. but now i am trying with your idea .. i will keep try .. thanks for your support

Answer (score 1):

Have the incrementi_Value return the value of i and check that value in your y loop.

incrementi_Value == 0 ? break : continue;

Change private static void incrementi_Value  -> private static int incrementi_Value

then place a return i; when you want to return the current value of i.

Comment: this is what i tried .. but i am not getting the output ... how to return the value of "i"

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `increamenti_Value()` being `void`, make it return `boolean` - true if the caller should break, false otherwise:

```
private static boolean increamenti_Value() {
    // return true if you want the caller to break
}
```

And instead of calling it like you are, call it like this:

```
if (increamenti_Value())
    break;
```

Note that a called method having knowledge of when the caller should do something doesn't seem like a good design. You may want to reconsider your logic.